# Selecting elements created with ModelBuilder gives selected ID -1000000000

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm creating geometries using code from https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-models-forge-viewer. When selecting custom geometries with selection mode FIRST_OBJECT, AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT is fired with a dbId of -1000000000.

Changing selection mode to LEAF_OBJECT is not an option because FIRST_OBJECT-mode is used for other reasons. Is it possible to use FIRST_OBJECT-mode and still get the correct DBID for custom geometries?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the heads up. Yes, when a custom model is created, i.e., it's just a single root node element referencing a flat list of geometries. The dbid of the root node is set to -1e9, and its type is set to `NODE_TYPE_ASSEMBLY (0x0)`, which is why the selection was behaving in an unexpected way when using the selection mode `FIRST_OBJECT`.

What's strange is that the type of the root node should be set to `NODE_TYPE_MODEL (0x5)` instead. I will report this to the engineering team, and in the meantime, you can set the `NODE_TYPE_MODEL` type to the root node manually to work around this issue.